# knowing the color below the text view

Tags: java, android

I have a `ImageView` on which I have a `TextView`. My default image view src is a Black Image,so I keep the `TextView` white in color.

If I had to set the color of `TextView` dynamically as per the background set by the user. Like if the user sets a background of white color or a image which has white color at the location of the text view, so I shall be able to change the color of the text view to black.

> I need to Read the color value at the location of the text view so
>   that to decide that.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Post some code showing what you have tried?

Comment: textView.getCurrentTextColor()

Answer (score 0):

Use the Palette class to extract the prominent colors of the background image.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html